# Home fuse box: bedroom breakers causing failure in parts of the circuit

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I'm a new home owner. A couple of days after moving in, the living room overhead fan/light stopped working. The outlets in one of the upstairs bathrooms have also stopped working.

When I went to the fuse box to investigate, I found this note:
[image: note]

The house was built in 2005. So far, I haven't been able to successfully execute this task, so I've been living without power in these outlets/fixtures..

Any idea what the actual problem or a fix might look like? I'd like to think I'm handy enough to fix this; I'd definitely like to avoid paying an electrician if I can. I'm suspicious that the PHO was also DIY-inclined, and installed the wrong kind of breaker (based on some other stack exchange questions).

[image: box]
[image: label3]
[image: label1]
[image: label2]

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of your breaker box's door please?

Comment: Good call, thank you! Hopefully these are readable. Please let me know if anything else would be valuable.. there are no labels on the case sidewall that I could find.

Comment: The three AFCI breakers look correct for 2005.  Are you sure this isn't as simple as *putting too much stuff on the circuit*?  A 15A circuit supports 15A (obviously) and that is 1800 watts.  Any large heat making appliance is 1500 watts. Any compressor/refrigerant appliance is up there too. Two A/Cs plus something else.  Do an appliance roundup, and get the amps or VA off each nameplate, and see what  you're actually putting on the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a Square D breaker in a Eaton/Cutler Hammer panel, it needs to be replaced, but not likely the cause of your problem.

The problem seems like loose connections. The bathroom receptacle and bedroom circuits should not be on the same breaker, you will likely find it is not a single loose connection fixing all your problems.

Arc Fault (AFCI) breakers are suppose to detect loose connections that could smolder and start a fire. They also trip for loose connections that just cause location specific meltdown. In 2005 production of AFCI was still a bit early in production cycle and you may have a defective breaker but at $40 each randomly replacing breakers gets expensive.

First thing that needs to be checked is proper termination in the panel for the breakers. You need to turn off main breaker and get a Torque Screwdriver and check the wire terminations on all the breakers. Check the torque setting on the panel cover.

Then you need to verify the proper connection of cables to the AFCI breakers, the black and white from the same cable need to be connected directly to the same breaker with no extra wires.

Then one at a time remove the wires from each breaker in question and see if it can be reset and test for voltage when connected to no wires.

Finally if you don't find problems you need to move on to checking for loose connections at all the receptacles and switches that have no power.

***Any time you remove a device be aware it may be hot, you may have some circuits off but the dead receptacle may be on another circuit that is hot and the incoming hot may be loose.***

Make sure all the device terminations are tight. If you have back-stab devices you should change to screw terminations. If you have more than one set of wires connected to a device you may need to create pigtail connections.

Comment: I see the panel cover defers to the individual breakers for torque settings.

Comment: Thank you so much - lots of great information here!

Comment: I should've noted: Crushed or nicked insulation could also be an issue. You may see evidence of that in junction boxes. Using a meg-ohm tester on individual cables if in the wall would probably necessary to locate, but honestly it is really beyond a homeowner repair.

Comment: Fair enough. There's a non-zero chance we wind up getting an electrician, but probably not before I at least take a look and try the first couple steps you've suggested.